# Inspecting records whose fields' types are the result of type-level computations

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation, servant

This came up in the context of the [servant](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-server) library, but the issue reappears in [other contexts](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/implementing-trees-that-grow/trees-that-grow-guidance).

[Servant](https://docs.servant.dev/en/stable/tutorial/index.html) allows you to define [named routes](https://www.tweag.io/blog/2022-02-24-named-routes/) using a record, like this:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingStrategies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
import GHC.Generics
import Servant

type API = NamedRoutes Counter

data Counter mode = Counter
  { counterPost :: mode :- Capture "stuff" Int :> PostNoContent,
    counterGet :: mode :- Get '[JSON] Int
  }
  deriving stock (Generic)
```

The type [`Server API`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-server-0.19.2/docs/Servant-Server.html#t:Server) will perform some type-level computation, which evaluates to the type

```
ghci> :kind! Server API
Server API :: *
= Counter (AsServerT Handler)
```

I would like a way to "peek into" the record type and inspect the final types of each field, which here would be the result of evaluating `AsServerT Handler :- Capture "stuff" Int :> PostNoContent` and `AsServerT Handler :- Get '[JSON] Int`.

But specifying those two expressions separatedly is inconvenient. I would like to pass the type `Server API` to... something, and get the evaluated type of all fields in return. Does such functionality exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that one way of getting the fields' types is through the generic representation:

```
ghci> :kind! Rep (Server API)
Rep (Server API) :: * -> *
= M1
    D
    ('MetaData "Counter" "Main" "main" 'False)
    (M1
       C
       ('MetaCons "Counter" 'PrefixI 'True)
       (M1
          S
          ('MetaSel
             ('Just "counterPost")
             'NoSourceUnpackedness
             'NoSourceStrictness
             'DecidedLazy)
          (K1 R (Int -> Handler NoContent))
        :*: M1
              S
              ('MetaSel
                 ('Just "counterGet")
                 'NoSourceUnpackedness
                 'NoSourceStrictness
                 'DecidedLazy)
              (K1 R (Handler Int))))
```

Kind of verbose, but it works and plays well with the ["Eval" code lens](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-language-server/issues/425) in VSCode:

[image]

For less verbosity, a [`Generics`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html)-based helper could produce a more manageable output. Using my [by-other-names](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/by-other-names) package, we can define:

```
recordFields ::
  forall r.
  (Generic r, GHasFieldNames (Rep r), GRecord Typeable (Rep r)) =>
  [(String, TypeRep)]
recordFields =
  Data.Foldable.toList $
    gRecordEnum @Typeable @(Rep r) gGetFieldNames typeRep
```

Which, put to use:

[image]